# ANTLR v4 + Xcode/objC/iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, antlr

Can one use ANTLR v4 on an Xcode/Objective-C iOS app?

If so, how does one write a hello, world project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. At least not until they publish runtime API for C/C++/Objective-C.

from [here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Runtime+Libraries+and+Code+Generation+Targets) you can see currently only Java and C# API is available. You can't run Java on ios device, I am not sure how C# api works with MonoTouch